# Raid 5 Failed drive with HS rebuilding

Tags: raid, failed

I have a Raid 5 setup with 3 drives and a hot spare drive.

- Hot spare Rebuilding - Very slow
- Drive one healthy
- Drive two healthy
- Drive three failed

Backups are failing on the raid.

My question is while the HS is rebuilding (which seems to be days) can I swap out drive 3 for a new one?
What are my options, without minimum downtime and dataloss?

Comment: Indeed, this is not a forum. For minimum risk of downtime or data loss you should avoid swapping a drive while the array is rebuilding, ABSOLUTELY. Let one thing finish then do the other one.

Comment: Also try not to use R5 at all - especially with 1TB+ 7.2krpm disks.

Comment: In the event of a mishap you'l be fine as I'm sure you have backups